# Nullpointexception when try run app only after app was closed by system(Android)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I noticed that my app only when is closed by system during open there is nullpointexception. 
Look I have Activity here I get data form db and create an object. Then I create new Fragment and set before created object to frament by setter.  And use fragment manager to display fragment.  Any here is a problem because in onCreate method field with my object is null.  I am sure I seted object and it wasnt null.

Activity where I get data from db and create Fragment

```
public class ActivityForSingle extends AppCompatActivity {
  Employee emloyee;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_for_single);
    ...

    getEmployee(); // here I get emplyee from db and create employee object

    SitePersonFragment f = new SitePersonFragment();
            f.setEmpoyee(employee); // here emplyee is not null
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frameForFragment, f, "USER_SITE").commit();


}


public class SitePersonFragment extends Fragment implements Update, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

 Employee employee;

  setEmployee(Employee e){
      this.emplyee = e;
  //here e and employee is not null
   }

  @Override
     public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

  //here employee is null
  // why??
 }
```

What happend?  I cannot debug because app is  destroyed.

Comment: What do you mean "by system"? You shouldn't use System.exit methods

Comment: And using setters on Fragments is often not recommended pattern for initializing objects. Please show your code as a [mcve]

Comment: by Android. Android when need more ram close another witch are not used I meant.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override
     public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    //here employee is null
    // why??
 }
```

Because the view might be created before you set the Employee.

Additionally, `getEmployee()`... does that return something? `emloyee` is never assigned in the code you posted. Why wouldn't it be null?

Related: [Best practice for instantiating a new Android Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment) (requires a Serializable or Parcelable class)

Comment: I'll check it tomorow.  I put log and check what is first  but I think first is setting Employee and after is `onViewCreated() `

Comment: Well, your question is not complete code, and it shouldn't compile, so I would recommend you fix that

Comment: It isnt complete but shows everything step by step.  Of course there is `onCreateView` in Fragment.

Comment: You should make it complete, but minimal, as I commented above. For example, there is no `pracownikFragment` and you misspelled `employee` in one of the variables

Comment: I changed 'pracownikFragment ` to `f`

Answer (score 0):

I changed 'pracownikFragment `to`f`